# Unknown chromium error: 0

Tags: android, cordova, sdk, ionic-framework, chromium

I'm working on a ionic/cordova web app for android. I've built it up and it has been working so far, that's until I updated the Android SDK to r24.3.3 from Android Studio and now, whenever I am sending a request to my host server I'm getting an 'Unknown chromium error: 0'.

Request is a GET request, tested on XmlHttpRequest and AngularJS's $http directive.

Access-origin is set to "*"

My Cordova version is 5.1.1.
Android SDK r24.3.3
Tested on Android 4.3.3 and Android 5.0.1 - both on simulator and an actual device.

Any ideas as to what might be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the plugin *cordova-plugin-whitelist* and add

```
<allow-navigation href="data:*"/>
```

or for whatever scope, in the config.xml

Comment: <3 Thanks! You made my day :D

Comment: I have the same problem, but, I didn't update android studio. What can be this problem?